# How can I input UTF-8 CJK character in .sty file

Tags: cjk

I compile my tex file with xelatex

and I want to renew the  `\lstlistlistingname`

In this case, I just use `\renewcommand` to do this job.

It success if I put this command after package in tex file

but how can I move this command to `.sty` file.

Notice, The new  `lstlistlistingname` is some CJK character and the file encoding with UTF-8

Comment: ? Where is your problem. If it is a personal style you can use utf8 chars if you want.

Comment: Do you input CJK enconding first and then redefine `lstlistlistingname`?

Comment: Which `.sty` file do you put it in? Please provide a [miniaml working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example works for me:

The package:

```
% encoding: UTF-8
% ccode.sty
\ProvidesPackage{ccode}[2012/06/22 test listings]
\RequirePackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{代码}
\lstnewenvironment{ccode}[2][]{\lstset{language=C,caption=#2,#1}}{}
\endinput
```

The test document:

```
% encoding: UTF-8
% foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ccode}
\begin{document}
\begin{ccode}{测试}
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello world.");
    return 0;
}
\end{ccode}
\end{document}
```